# What is the device of inode?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I'm messing with the [stat structure](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html)
and trying to comprehend it, however most of the documentation is rather cryptic, specifically, I can't understand the purpose of the first member, **st_dev**, what exactly is a "*device of inode*"?

Comment: Where are you seeing the phrase "device of inode"? The documentation you linked to says "Device ID of device containing file." ("device of inode" wouldn't make sense.)

Comment: @KeithThompson that was from K&R, nevermind

Comment: definitely not eligible for C tag

Comment: I think that's just poor wording in K&R. The POSIX documentation you linked to seems clearer.

Comment: @kkk: Sure it is. `stat` is defined as a C function. (BTW, you might consider changing your user name; the initials "KKK" have very bad implications in American English.)

Comment: how about potato ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the field *st_dev* you find a system-dependent number of the device which backs this file. It usually is the major/minor number (combined with `makedev(3)`) of the block device which contains the filesystem where the file is located on. If the file is a device node, it is the major/minor number of the device itself.

For example:

```
$ ls -la /dev/null
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 May 17 09:52 /dev/null
```

st_dev will contain `makedev(1,3)` (which is 259 on linux), or

for `/etc/passwd`, st_dev will contain `makedev(8,1)` (which is 2049 on linux), if the file is located on /dev/sda1.

You can extract the major/minor number with the corresponding macros `major(st_dev)` and `minor(st_dev)`, as described in the manpage for `makedev(3)`.

Comment: Perfect! That explains the numbers